# Split the string 'abcde' into a list with separate elements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string like `'g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb'`. I use the `.split()` function in python and get `['g', 'fmnc', 'wms', 'bgblr', 'rpylqjyrc', 'gr', 'zw', 'fylb']`

Now I want to split each of the elements into seperated lists like: `[['g'], [['f'],['m'],['n'],['c']],...]` and so on.

My problem is to split the element `['abcbd']` into `[['a'],['b'],['c'],['b'],['d']]`

Comment: `[['g'], [['f'],['m'],['n'],['c']],...]` seems wrong. The 'g' is inside two nested listed, but the 'f' is inside three nested lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
[list(item) for item in s.split()]
```

It will give you this `[['g'], ['f', 'm', 'n', 'c'], ...]` which isn't quite what you asked for, but probably what you meant.

Comment: Dude, you answered in about 16 seconds. How's that even possible? Do you poll for new questions?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> sample = 'g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb'
>>> [ list(x) for x in sample.split() ]
[['g'], ['f', 'm', 'n', 'c'], ['w', 'm', 's'], ['b', 'g', 'b', 'l', 'r'], ['r', 'p', 'y', 'l', 'q', 'j', 'y', 'r', 'c'], ['g', 'r'], ['z', 'w'], ['f', 'y', 'l', 'b']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a='g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb'
ml = lambda x: len(x) == 1 and [x] or map(ml, x)
print ml(a.split())

[['g'], [['f'], ['m'], ['n'], ['c']], [['w'], ['m'], ['s']], [['b'], ['g'], ['b'], ['l'], ['r']], [['r'], ['p'], ['y'], ['l'], ['q'], ['j'], ['y'], ['r'], ['c']], [['g'], ['r']], [['z'], ['w']], [['f'], ['y'], ['l'], ['b']]]
```